# SwiftUI simple question following Apple's guide

Tags: ios, swiftui, mkmapview

I just started to follow Apple's SwiftUI course on there site named [creating and combining views](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views).

And I noticed a strange behaviour I cant understand in the code there showing in the ContentView struct, here is the code and an image of the result.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        MapView()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .frame(height: 300)
        
        CircleImage()
            .offset(y : -130)
            .padding(.bottom, -130)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Turtle Rock")
                .font(.title)
            HStack {
                Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                Spacer()
                Text("California")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Noting special here, but when changing the order of the modifiers for the MapView to.

```
        MapView()
            .frame(height: 300)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

The center of the circleView is not in the bottom of the mapView anymore, see image.

[image]

I noticed that this will not happen when I remove the Spacer() in the bottom,

So, what really happens here ? why the order of the modifiers matters ? and how the Spacer() effect other views in that way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is why: [Why modifier order matters](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-modifier-order-matters). Because you're creating a frame without ignoring the safe area on your second code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Why modifier order matters](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-modifier-order-matters).

Because you're creating a frame without ignoring the safe area on your second code.

Also when you add spacer your bottom sheet just becomes higher. So it looks good but it's not effective at all.

In this case, it's better you put your circular image and bottom content in the same container. So it will be always centered. For example:

```
VStack {
    CircleImage()
        .offset(y : -130)
        .padding(.bottom, -130)
    
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Turtle Rock")
            .font(.title)
        HStack {
            Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
                .font(.subheadline)
            Spacer()
            Text("California")
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
    }
    .padding()
    
    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ! I do hope that there is some decent constraint system because part of the problem is the hardcoded offset, guess I will find out

Comment: Yes, I agree. Tt's not effective too :) I think they don't care because they're trying to focus essentials of the tutorial.